# Jquery applying css to load div

Tags: jquery, css, load, live

I am having an issue applying css dynamically to a loaded div using the `load()` function. The html being loaded is found, and it is inserted, and I can use a close command. However the css I am trying to apply is not being registered. Everything seems to work fine minus the dynamic css. I think I may have something wrong or an incorrect function here:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Find & Open
    $(".projectThumb").click(function(){
        htmlName = $(this).find("img").attr("name");
        $("#popupContainer").load(htmlName + ".html");
        });

    //Apply CSS
    $(".projectPopup").css({"position": "absolute", "background": "#000", "top": "10%", "left": "10px"});

    //Close property
    $("a.close").live("click", function(){
        $("#popupContainer").empty();
        });
});
```

test.php:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="projectThumb">
      <img src="/img/aeffect_button_static.gif" name="aeffect" />
      <p class="title">title</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="popupContainer"></div>
```

aeffect.html:

```
<div class="projectPopup" id="aeffect">
  <a class="close">Close &times;</a>
  <p class="description">Description</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the CSS properties at the wrong time. What you need to do is apply the CSS properties after the load completes using the callback function of the load() method.

```
 $("#popupContainer").load(htmlName + ".html", {}, function(){
     $(".projectPopup").css({"position": "absolute", "background": "#000", "top": "10%", "left": "10px"});
 });
```

Comment: Awesome, I guess it has to load inline with the popup. Thanks for this!

Comment: The element projectPopup does not exist when the page first loads and the $(document).ready() executes when the page loads. At that time it finds no element that matches $(".projectPopup"). After the AJAX load() method runs the element propejctPopUp now exist so thats why it works when accessed from the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Put the apply CSS in the callback for the .load()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Find & Open
    $(".projectThumb").click(function(){
        htmlName = $(this).find("img").attr("name");   
        $("#popupContainer").load(htmlName + ".html", null, function(){
            //Apply CSS
            $("projectPopup").css({"position": "absolute", "background": "#000", "top": "10%", "left": "10px"});

        });




    //Close property
    $("a.close").live("click", function(){
        $("#popupContainer").empty();
        });
});
```